# Non-degeneracy of pairing between vector space and its dual - but without Choice

Tags: linear-algebra, axiom-of-choice

Let $V$ be some $k$-vector space, $v,w\in V$. How can we see that

$$\gamma(v) = \gamma(w) \quad\forall \gamma\in V^* \quad \implies \quad v = w?$$

This question can be rephrased as

> Prove that the pairing $V^*\times V\to k,$ $(\gamma,v)\mapsto\gamma(v)$ is non-degenerate (at least on the second argument).

It is painfully obvious if you allow choice: Just take any old basis. **BAM.**

But can we prove this without using a basis? I don't know, and my advisor couldn't come up with a proof either.

Comment: What does it mean: "BAM"?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bam#Interjection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If $k$ is any field, then it is consistent that there is a vector space $V$ over $k$ such that: (1) $V$ is nonzero; (2) the only endomorphisms of $V$ are scalar multiplication.

These conditions in conjunction imply that there are no non-zero functionals from $V$ to $k$. In particular, you cannot separate points in $V$ using functionals from $V^*$.

This was my masters thesis, building on an originally lesser known proof by Läuchli from the 1960s (I believe it was his Ph.D. thesis).

Additionally, one can obtain similar results from theorems about Banach spaces and the Hahn–Banach theorem's failure. Specifically, if every set of reals has the Baire property, then $\ell^\infty/c_0$ has a trivial dual.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't expect the answer to be negative! Is your thesis online? And I guess you mean Hans Läuchli, whose PhD thesis is called [_Auswahlaxiom in der Algebra_](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566957.pdf), I linked it for anyone interested. (You need to understand German, though)

Comment: Yes, that is who I meant. My thesis can be found on my homepage (in the Papers page), and the link is on my user profile.

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, if you feel that you've used some consequence of choice in a significant way, expect the answer to be consistency negative. That's what I had learned in eight years of working with the axiom of choice.

Comment: I don't think I have that kind of intuition :) And while the AC keeps nagging me I try to be one who does not lose much sleep over it.

Comment: Well, if you ever spend a summer in a hot country like Israel, you'd find that a lack of AC will certainly keep you up at night. Unless you have no problem sleeping with several fans.